# Creating plain text element using generated HL7 classes

Tags: java, xml, text, jaxb

In an old java 1.5 webservice the response message was constructed from a String containing the XML, this does not seem to work correctly anymore when migrating the webservice to java 7.
So, I generated classes with the existing HL7 WSDL, in order to create a java object-model which will map onto an XML using Jaxb. So, according to the old webservice, inside the acknowledgementDetail the tag  should appear, like this:

```
<acknowledgement typeCode="CE">
        <acknowledgementDetail typeCode="E">
           <text>Some text</text>
        </acknowledgementDetail>
</acknowledgement>
```

However, the method setText() of the generated acknowledgementDetail class only accepts an object of the type org.hl7.v3.ED or its subclasses.

The generated ED class has only one relevant method: a list of elements (List) accessible through ed.getAny()

```
ED ed = new ED();
ed.getAny().add(document.getDocumentElement());
acknowledgementDetail.setText(ed);
acknowledgement.getAcknowledgementDetail().add(acknowledgementDetail);
```

I created the above "document" like this:

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

try {
     documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     document = documentBuilder.newDocument();                           
     Node node = document.createElement("dummy");
     node.setTextContent("Some text");                             
     document.appendChild(node);                
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    sLog.error("ParserConfigurationException: ", e);
}
```

To me this seems an awfull lot of work for just a piece of String, but that's besides the point here...

When I create an org.w3c.dom.Element, I am forced to give the Element a name ("dummy" in this case), or else Jaxb will fail with an exception.
The result I keep getting is like this:

```
<acknowledgement typeCode="CE">
    <acknowledgementDetail typeCode="E">
        <text>
            <dummy xmlns="">Some text</dummy>
        </text>
    </acknowledgementDetail>
</acknowledgement>
```

In the documentation for the ED class it says subclass ST should be used for text, so changing type ED to type ST and adding:

```
st.setRepresentation(CsBinaryDataEncoding.TXT);
```

results in the following:

```
<acknowledgement typeCode="CE">
    <acknowledgementDetail typeCode="E">
        <text representation="TXT" xsi:type="ST">
            <dummy xmlns="">Some text</dummy>
        </text>
     </acknowledgementDetail>
</acknowledgement>
```

... which obviously does not solve my problem :S

I don't get it, how do I get plain text inside the  element?!?
Any suggestions will be welcome, this just needs to be finished and working asap, so any possible workarounds would be welcome as well!

UPDATE:

AcknowledgementDetail complextype:

```
<xs:complexType name="MCCI_MT000200.AcknowledgementDetail">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="code" type="CE" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="text" type="ED" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="location" type="ST" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="type" type="Classes" default="AcknowledgementDetail"/>
<xs:attribute name="typeCode" type="cs" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="templateId" use="optional">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:list itemType="oid"/>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="typeID" use="optional">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:list itemType="oid"/>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="realmCode" use="optional">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list itemType="cs"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="cs" use="optional"/>
```

ED complextype:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ED" mixed="true">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation> Data that is primarily intended for human interpretation or for
            further machine processing is outside the scope of HL7. This includes unformatted or
            formatted written language, multimedia data, or structured information as defined by
            a different standard (e.g., XML-signatures.) Instead of the data itself, an ED may
            contain only a reference (see TEL.) Note that the ST data type is a specialization
            of the ED data type when the ED media type is text/plain.</xsd:documentation>
        <xsd:appinfo/>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xsd:extension base="BIN">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="reference" type="TEL" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation> A telecommunication address (TEL), such as a URL for
                            HTTP or FTP, which will resolve to precisely the same binary data
                            that could as well have been provided as inline data.</xsd:documentation>
                        <xsd:appinfo/>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="thumbnail" type="thumbnail" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="mediaType" type="cs" use="optional" default="text/plain">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation> Identifies the type of the encapsulated data and
                        identifies a method to interpret or render the data.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo/>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="language" type="cs" use="optional">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation> For character based information the language property
                        specifies the human language of the text.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo/>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="compression" type="cs_CompressionAlgorithm" use="optional">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation> Indicates whether the raw byte data is compressed, and
                        what compression algorithm was used.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo/>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="integrityCheck" type="bin" use="optional">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation> The integrity check is a short binary value representing
                        a cryptographically strong checksum that is calculated over the binary
                        data. The purpose of this property, when communicated with a reference
                        is for anyone to validate later whether the reference still resolved to
                        the same data that the reference resolved to when the encapsulated data
                        value with reference was created.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo/>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="integrityCheckAlgorithm" type="cs_IntegrityCheckAlgorithm"
                use="optional" default="SHA-1">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation> Specifies the algorithm used to compute the
                        integrityCheck value.</xsd:documentation>
                    <xsd:appinfo/>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Could you post the portion of your XML schema that corresponds to the `text` element?  And what does your `ED` class look like?

Comment: Post updated with XML part. As for the ED-class, it is generated from the WSDL. Both should not be changed. Here is what the ED-class looks like: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.connectopensource/CONNECTCommonTypesLib/4.0.2/org/hl7/v3/ED.java 
Mine is almost identical, except for "@XmlType(name = "ED", propOrder = { "reference", "thumbnail", "any" })" (my generator added "any" for some reason)

Comment: What does the `ED` complex type look like?

Comment: Post above updated with ED complextype.

Comment: Found out I need a STjlStringAdapter. http://i-proving.com/2007/10/17/understanding-hl7-data-types/ Can't find a download for a HL7 library anywhere though, this is so frustrating...

Comment: OK, STjlStringAdapter seems to be old crap :S

Comment: I eventually resorted to changing the generated AcknowledgementDetail class, which held an instance of ED, to be of type String instead of ED. This is in fact an ugly hack, but I never need to generate the classes again and the resulting XML is now of the correct format. The result is what matters, so F. it...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resorted to hacking the generated acknowledgementDetail's setText-method to accept a String instead of an ED. This is very ugly of course, but it seems to work fine when marshalling to the output XML, and I couldn't be bothered with finding the right solution any longer.